# Error when try to run my project in cmd

Tags: java, javac

I have a structure code like this :

[image]

I want to run my program using mcd using javac, like this : javac ListenerZipFile.java. The result like :

[image]

Why i can't run my program?

Comment: You're importing a package which does not exist or is not included in your classpath: _error: package net.contentobjects.jnotify does not exist_

Comment: A) you cant run it because you are trying to compile it. B) you have errors on your code (as mentioned by Keews) and you cant compile it. Can you build/compile/run under Eclipse(You are using eclipse right?)

Comment: @SkarosIlias yes i run it under eclipse.

Comment: @Keews i have jars in my lib source code. but, when i try to run using javac ListenerZipFile.java, the program show many errors.

Comment: There is an answer from @12dollar right behind which tells you how to point out to your classpath!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems here.

1. Incorrect directory location for compiling packed classes.
2. classpath no set correctly.

Consider you have, source_dir = D:\~\~\src, jar_location = D:\~\~\lib and package is com.example then your steps to compile are:

- cd to $source_dir
- $source_dir> set classpath=.;jar_location
- $source_dir> javac com\example\Examples1.java or $source_dir> javac com\example\*.java

As per path shared, command to compile should be :

```
cd C:\ListenerZipfile\src
javac -cp .;C:\ListenerZipfile\lib\*.jar com\sigma\main\ListenerZipFile.java
```

Command to run java program with above path:

```
java -cp .;C:\ListenerZipfile\lib\*.jar com.sigma.main.ListenerZipFile
```

Comment: i have do this : `javac -cp .jar;.\lib\commons-io-2.4.jar;.\lib\commons-logging.jar;.\lib\jnotify-0.94.jar;.\lib\joda-time-1.6.jar;.\lib\log4j-1.2.11.jar; com.xxx.main.ListenerZipFile.java`. but i still get an error like `javac: file not found: com.sigma.main.ListenerZipFile.java.`

Comment: I have updated answer with shared paths...see compilation command

Comment: I have updated answer with run command. I suggest do some reading otherwise you will always get stuck here and there.

Answer (score 2):

you are using a package without telling javac where it is located (jnotify for example).

you'd have to use it like:

```
javac -classpath "path/to/jnotify-0.94.jar" test.java
```

Comment: can you tell me, the example of classpath. i don't get it.

Comment: javac -cp "C:/MikeTyson/MyProject/lib/jnotify-0.94.jar";"C:/MikeTyson/MyProject/lib/IamAjarFile.jar" ListenerZipFile.java

Answer (score 0):

if you are using eclipse (from the screen shot i think you do) then
right click on your project->Properties->Java Build Path, click on Libraries tab->click on "Add External JARs" button-> pick your jar and click OK to close all windows.
This should solve your problem, if your problem is jar dependencies

Comment: i have jars in my lib source code. but i still get errors

Comment: did you just copy-paste/move the jars there? if so do what i posted and will solve your problem